# I want to install Vulkan in order to use UnrealEnginge and Carla simulator

Tags: unreal-engine4, vulkan, carla

I only see installation tutorials for Nvidia and AMD.
Can someone help me install Vulkan?

[image: GPU info]

Comment: If you do not have NV or AMD GPU, then what GPU **do** you have?